# how to change the way DatePicker shows Date

Tags: flutter, datepicker

I want to change the way DatePicker shows the Date, so that it shows
`day/month/year`. As of right now it shows in the format of `year/month/day` and I'm not sure on how to change this. I've been searching a lot but couldn't find the right way to do this.

I will show my code below, hopefully someone can help me :D

Thank you in Advance guys.

```
class WFDatePickerField extends DateTimeField {
  final bool? hasError;
  final bool hasErrorDecoration;
  final double? errorHeight;
  final dynamic error;
  final DateTimeValue value;
  final TextStyle? errorStyle;

  WFDatePickerField(
      {Key? key,
      required this.value,
      required String labelText,
      String hintText = '',
      TextEditingController? controller,
      FormFieldValidator<DateTime>? validator,
      FloatingLabelBehavior? floatingLabelBehavior =
          FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
      String format = 'dd.MM.yyyy',
      final InputDecoration? decoration,
        this.errorStyle,
      this.hasError,
      this.hasErrorDecoration=false,
      this.error,
      this.errorHeight})
      : super(
          key: key,
          decoration: ErrorDecorationSelector(hasError, hasErrorDecoration, errorHeight, error, value, errorStyle).getDecoration(),
          readOnly: true,
          style: AppTheme()
              .textStyles
              .bodyText1!
              .copyWith(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5)),
          initialValue: value.value,
          format: DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy'),
          controller: controller,
          validator: validator,
          onShowPicker: (context, currentValue) async {
            DateTime? newDate;
            String? deviceLocale = await (Devicelocale.currentLocale);
            LocaleType locale =
                deviceLocale != null && deviceLocale.contains('de')
                    ? LocaleType.de
                    : LocaleType.en;
            await DatePicker.showDatePicker(context,
                minTime: DateTime(1900, 1, 1),
                maxTime: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 18,
                    DateTime.now().month, DateTime.now().day),
                locale: locale,
                onConfirm: (date) => newDate = date);
            return newDate;
          },
          onChanged: (newValue) {
            value.value = newValue;
          },
        );


}
```

[image]

Comment: Am I right supposing that you're using a `showDatePicker` coming from a third party package and not the one [provided by Flutter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDatePicker.html)?

Comment: @il_boga I'm using this package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_datetime_picker

Comment: Well, seems like you have to wait for that function to be implemented: [see here](https://github.com/Realank/flutter_datetime_picker/pull/286) (unless you already know, if you're the author of that PR)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I forked that repo and then could access the attribute. Thank you very much @il_boga

Answer (score 0):

if I'M not mistaken your trying to format the date if that is what you're asking
[enter link description here][1]

// Use this link it is flutter intl dateFormater it has different style
**[1]: https://pub.dev/packages/intl**